# How to run Racket in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, racket

I don't like DrRacket because it does not have convenient edit capabilities as Emacs, however I can only run Scheme file through adding command "racket current-file.scm" in `.emacs`, now, I want to run the Scheme file in Emacs described as "Run : Resets the interactions window and runs the program in the definitions window." in [DrRacket's manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Menus.html#%28part._menu~3aracket%29), I read the command Racket's help "[19.1 Running racket and gracket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/racket.html)", seemingly it doesn't answer my question, what should I do?

Comment: I remember there were something related to activating emacs shortcuts in drracket settings (I think it was something like `disabling menu shortcuts`). Also have you seen [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html)?

Comment: I used quack, and I can execute scheme file in emacs! but I want to have the similar "the interactions window and runs the program in the definitions window" as described in 3.1.5 Racket

Comment: Did you find a solution to this abelard20008?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to try [Geiser](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/) mode for Emacs. There is also a [section](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/other-editors.html) in the Racket Guide dedicated to describing how to use other editors and CLI tools.

Update: Nowadays I also highly recommend Greg Hendershott's [racket-mode](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode) as well.

Comment: @albelard20008: in particular, there's a whole section on integrating with Emacs in: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html

Answer (score 2):

The racket-lang official website provides some ways to use racket in emacs. Here is the link [racket-lang emacs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Emacs.html). You can use [quack](http://www.neilvandyke.org/quack/) or geiser.

Answer (score 2):

Greg Hendershott has written `racket-mode` for using Racket from Emacs.

```
https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode
```

See the presentation from 2014 RacketCon here:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QWiteH8PARQ&noredirect=1
```